# how to store html 'select' control input to the JSON object using ng-model in AngularJS?

Tags: json, angularjs

i am binding the 'select' input control to each row using ng-repeat.After binding i want to store the selected value in the 'select' control to JSON object using ng-model.how to acieve this?

my code:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(refreshments,price) in items">
           <td>
             <label>{{refreshments}}</label>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:500px">
            </td>
            <td>
              <label>{{price}}</label>
            </td>
            <td class="td_width">
            </td>
            <td>
               <select ng-model="quantity">
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
               </select>
            </td>
           </tr>
  </table>
```

JSON object:

```
var JSONObject= {"quantity":"{{ quantity }}"};
```

Just i need to bind the selected quantity in the JSON Object.
my ng-repeat has morethan one row & for each row i am binding the select option through ng-repeat.

Thanks in advance,
Stephen.L

Comment: take a look at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
var JSONObject = {};
JSONObject.quantity = scope.quantity;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var JSONObject = {};
$scope.$watch('quantity', function(newValue) {
    JSONObject.quantity = newValue;
});
```

**Explaination**

`$scope`'s `$watch` method registers a listener callback which will be executed every time when model value (in your case `quantity`) is changed. So you can be sure that `JSONObject.quantity` property always reflects an actual `quantity` state.

More details you can find in a [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope).

Comment: Perhaps explain why in your answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, you are right. I should write an explaination to my answer. Thank you for the remark :)

Comment: Not working :( question is simple, my select control is inside my ng-repeat. so i am not able to get the value of input control.not 'select' if we put text input control also ng-model is not working ... is there is anyother way or its not possible?

Comment: @user2927385 take a look at [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk7xG/). Is this what you need?

Comment: @Zub i am getting Quantity: [ "\n 1\n ", "\n 2\n ", "\n 3\n " ] like this with '\n' when i am binding the 'select' from JSON using ng-repeat how to avoid '\n'. Code: <td ng-controller="Quantity">
                        <select ng-model="quantity[$index]">
                          <option ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = data[key]">
                            {{key}}
                      </select>
                      </td>

Comment: @StephenL you should write `<option ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = data[key]">{{key}}</select>` in one line, i.e. without line breaks.

Comment: @Zub - AngularJS is working fine in jsbin & jsfiddle, but when i create my own html page Angulajs not working ... how i will give reference?where to download angular-min.js?      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>    i tried downloading lot and gave reference its not working ... help me ....

Comment: @StephenL if you use Chrome, hit F12 then go to Network tab and reload a page. You will see several requests. Find angular.min.js. If it's red and you see 404 error, that means that you wrote wrong angular path. In this case try this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>`